# Where to put 'Where' clause for query from Firebase Database in Ionic Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angularfire2

**My Firebase Cloud Database:** 
[image]

**Service to get the all data from Firebase:**

```
 getTodos(){
     return this.todos = this.todosCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data};
        });
      })
    );
   }
```

Now, I want to query with specific Month and Year, **suppose ('01-2019')** from **myDate** field in my Firebase database.

But, I am stuck in where to put my **Where** clause for query?

Comment: I think you can't use variable assignment in return statement.

Comment: I am taking the user input from a Month Year Calendar from the user. And in the console I'm getting '01-2019'. Then I have query from Database from this specific type of Month and Year.  @KonradSitarz

Comment: Is it firebase data store or Firestore ?

Comment: @HilalKaldane Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for using firebase queries in ionic Angular hope so you'll get it.

```
  const data = this.database.collection('policy', ref => 
               ref.where('customerUid', '==', item.id )).get();
  data.forEach(querySnap =>{
   querySnap.forEach(query=>{
     policyId = query.id
   })
  }).then( res=>{
    console.log(policyId)

  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err)
    alert("Oops something went wrong")
  })
}
```